# SQL: Flattening Sets of Rows Based on Some Condition

Tags: sql

I am working with Netezza SQL.

I have the following table ("my_table"):

```
  id_1 id_2  color start_date   end_date
1  111  222    red 2010-01-01 2010-05-05
2  111  222    red 2010-05-05 2011-01-01
3  111  222    red 2011-01-01 2012-01-01
4  111  666   blue 2012-01-01 2012-05-05
5  111  444  green 2012-05-05 2013-01-01
6  111  444  green 2013-01-01 2013-06-06
7  333  555 yellow 2020-01-01 2020-05-05
```

**My Question:** I am trying to accomplish the following :

- For a given set of id_1 and id_2
- If they keep the same color over a range of dates
- I want to "flatten" that set into a single record

This would look something like this:

```
id_1 id_2  color start_date   end_date
1  111  222    red 2010-01-01 2012-01-01
4  111  666   blue 2012-01-01 2012-05-05
5  111  444  green 2012-05-05 2013-06-06
7  333  555 yellow 2020-01-01 2020-05-05
```

**Can someone please show me how to do this?**

Here is my attempt:

**Attempt 1:**

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT
        id_1,
        id_2,
        color,
        start_date,
        end_date,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id_1, id_2 ORDER BY start_date) - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id_1, id_2, color ORDER BY start_date) AS grp
    FROM my_table
)
SELECT
    id_1,
    id_2,
    color,
    MIN(start_date) AS start_date,
    MAX(end_date) AS end_date
FROM CTE
GROUP BY
    id_1,
    id_2,
    color,
    grp
ORDER BY
    start_date;
```

**Attempt 2:**

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT
        id_1,
        id_2,
        color,
        start_date,
        end_date,
        CASE
            WHEN LAG(color) OVER (PARTITION BY id_1, id_2 ORDER BY start_date) = color THEN 0
            ELSE 1
        END AS new_grp
    FROM my_table
),
CTE2 AS (
    SELECT
        id_1,
        id_2,
        color,
        start_date,
        end_date,
        SUM(new_grp) OVER (PARTITION BY id_1, id_2 ORDER BY start_date) AS grp
    FROM CTE
)
SELECT
    id_1,
    id_2,
    color,
    MIN(start_date) AS start_date,
    MAX(end_date) AS end_date
FROM CTE2
GROUP BY
    id_1,
    id_2,
    color,
    grp
ORDER BY
    start_date;
```

Thanks!

**Note:** Original Data (my_table):

```
(
    id_1 = c(111,111,111,111, 111,111,333),
    id_2 = c(222,222,222, 666, 444, 444, 555),
    color = c("red", "red", "red", "blue", "green", "green", "yellow"),
    start_date = c("2010-01-01", "2010-05-05", "2011-01-01", "2012-01-01" , "2012-05-05", "2013-01-01", "2020-01-01"),
                   end_date = c("2010-05-05", "2011-01-01", "2012-01-01", "2012-05-05", "2013-01-01", "2013-06-06", "2020-05-05")
    )
```

Comment: @ Eric: I have tried  something and even have a draft answer that I think might work ... but every time I post my work here, I always get told to post my question on a different stackoverflow website. would you like to see what I have tried?

Comment: if you post your code, we can correct it if it's not working.

Comment: Does `id_2` always reflect a unique color? I'm not sure that the sample data covers the scenarios you're trying to handle.

Comment: Or using the language of the question above: What do you want to see if it doesn't "keep" the same color?

Answer (score 1):

When I run your attempt, it returns the same values as your example table. That being the case, I took your attempt code and simplified it.

The code below gets the same results but without the CTE and window function.

```
SELECT id_1
      ,id_2
      ,color
      ,MIN(start_date) AS start_date
      ,MAX(end_date) AS end_date
FROM my_table
GROUP BY id_1
        ,id_2
        ,color
ORDER BY start_date
```

Comment: This will not satisfy "If they keep the same color over a range of dates" condition.

Comment: I missed that and went primarily off of the example dataset and desired result. Looking at that now, it's much less clear to me what is actually being asked here.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Th query below uses `lead` to produce a temporary marker for all instances of consecutive dates for each color block, and then groups on the markers:

```
with cte as (
   select t.*, lead(t.start_date) over (order by t.id) = t.end_date and lead(t.color) over (order by t.id) = t.color r 
   from my_table t
)
select t1.id_1, t1.id_2, t1.color, t1.d1, t1.d2 from (
   select t.id_1, t.id_2, t.color, t.k, min(t.start_date) d1, max(t.end_date) d2
   from (select c.*, (select sum(c1.id < c.id and c1.r = 0 and c1.color = c.color) from cte c1) k from cte c) t
   group by t.id_1, t.id_2, t.color, t.k) t1
```

[See fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/4bXBtQM6).

Answer (score 1):

See example

```
with t as(
select *
  ,lag(id_1,1,id_1)over(order by start_date,end_date) id_1L
  ,lag(id_2,1,id_2)over(order by start_date,end_date) id_2L
  ,lag(color,1,color)over(order by start_date,end_date) colorL
from my_table
)
,t2 as(
select *
  ,case when id_1=id_1L and id_2=id_2L and color=colorL then 0
   else 1
   end gap
  ,sum(case when id_1=id_1L and id_2=id_2L and color=colorL then 0
   else 1
   end)over(order by start_date,end_date) gr -- sum of gap
from t
)
select min(id_1)id_1,min(id_2) id_2,min(color)color
  ,min(start_date) start_date,max(end_date) end_date
from t2
group by gr 
order by min(start_date)
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/2bgZ1GGk)